# Empty screen when logging in

Tags: 16.04

[image]Hi guys I have an issue with my operating system, after entering my password I get stuck in the following screen, unable to see anything, enter the terminal or use any command.

Please help me fix this issue.
I dont know if it is related but the only thing i did that is new was install a new font using `font-manager` packge

Comment: Does moving the cursor to upper left corner show a menu ?

Comment: @SorenA no it does not

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried restarting it before anything else? Also you can try entering into terminal via `ctrl-Alt-F1` and try removing that specific font-manager and `reboot the os`